# web3.js ETH events log - How to convert javascript big number into WEI

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I have a js script that used to work fine with getting events in the proper format -

```
receipt.events.MyEvent.returnValues.marketShare
```

but reading events that way seems to no longer work. So I edited my script to read the logs and use `web3.eth.abi.decodeLog`.

```
var eventAbi = [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "earnings",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "marketShare",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
    ];

var myEvent = web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(eventAbi, receipt.logs[1].data, receipt.logs[1].topics);
```

This seems to return fine, however my numbers are returning as such -

```
earnings: 32n
marketShare: 47691443057146912922899395050909650362856399929838832537703884369061582418996n
```

I need it to return the WEI or ETH value (at this point I'll take either or and convert later). So I've tried -

```
    console.log(myEvent.marketShare.toLocaleString());

    console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(myEvent.marketShare, "ether"));

    console.log(myEvent.marketShare.toNumber());

    console.log(myEvent.marketShare.toFixed());

    console.log(web3.utils.toBN(myEvent.marketShare));
```

I'm not having any luck getting the correct values, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you link the specific transaction hash that you're retrieving the `receipt` from? It will enable us to see the original data.

Comment: @PetrHejda I'm unable to provide a link but I can edit my question with any more specific details needed to help clarify

Comment: Ok it would be helpful if you can please share the `topics` (array of hex strings) and `data` (hex string) values of the event log. And also the Solidity event declaration (incl. the params and whether they're `indexed` or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to step away from the project for a while but was able to get things figured out.

My current script uses the following code to get the events and values --

```
await collection.getPastEvents('MyEvent', {
                                fromBlock: 'latest',  
                                toBlock: 'latest'
                            }, function(error, events){ console.log(events); })
                                .then(function(events){
                                let someEventValue = events[0].returnValues.someVar
                            });
```

The event values are retrieved within the `contract.methods` receipt function - `.on('receipt', async function(receipt) ...`

Answer (score 1):

`web3.utils.fromWei function` expects a `string, number, or BN (BigNumber)` object as input, so you’ll need to convert the `BigInt` to one of these types before passing it to the `fromWei` function.

```
var marketShare = myEvent.marketShare.toString();
var marketShareInEther = web3.utils.fromWei(marketShare, "ether");
console.log(marketShareInEther);
```